# JBoss "other" security domain

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

What is the significance of the other security domain in JBoss. I am new to JBoss and read the documentation but cannot understand why it is used.

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    </login-module>
    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

What would happen if I just remove these two modules? Given that my application has my own domain specific security domain defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have various security domains elements configured in JBoss. They can be referenced via `jboss-web.xml` files in different web projects if you want to have different security levels for different war's.

`other` is the *default* security domain. It can be removed (replaced with something more sophisticated), just be sure to remove its references also.